# how to concate ca, client-cert and key file and update it using update-ca-certificate on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

I created a self-signed ssl certificate. And i have **ca.pem**, **client-cert.pem** and **client-key.pem**. How can i concate them and update-ca-certificate with those certificates on ubuntu

Comment: If you have a self signed certificate, you do not have the CA or said differently the certificate is its own CA. However please note that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: `update-ca-certificate` is for updating CA certificates. A client certificate is not a CA certificate and thus `update-ca-certificate` will not help.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, update-ca-certificate can add the self-signed certificate. I concate them to bundle.crt and add to /usr/local/share/ folder. Then run update-ca-certificate, and it worked perfectly!